# angularjs app back button

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an angularjs and ionic app where in on the first screen I call the yelp api and display the results in the next screen. When I hit the back button and click on another request the yelp API gets executed but user is not redirected to the results screen.

I have a controller that calls the service to fetch the yelp results.

Can anyone suggest what could be issue?

Thanks

Comment: What are you using for routing?

Comment: I was able to resolve it by adding callback=JSON_CALLBACK instead of callback=angular_callback_.0

Comment: Interesting. That's usually for JSONP calls.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by adding callback=JSON_CALLBACK instead of callback=angular_callback_.0 –